# Beanstalkd failover for queues in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, beanstalkd

Does anyone know about a robust failover mechanism for Laravel queues?

At one point my beanstalkd server had some kind of error (still figuring out what went wrong) triggering `Pheanstalk_Exception_ConnectionException` in the Laravel (4) queue driver. As a result, new jobs couldn't be pushed to the queue.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have some sort of failover driver for `QueueInterface` which can take multiple instances of drivers, so I can define for example the 'sync' or 'redis' driver as a failover queue. Then as soon as beanstalkd fails, jobs will be executed by this driver and no work will be lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just going to take a really small stab at this for you and hope that it gives an idea... i think everyone has different needs for queues, so this is just what I have done.

To be honest I kind of just stripped out a bunch of my code to try and simplify what I did.  Try to make some sense out of it I guess.

In your queue config :

```
'connections' => array(
    'beanstalkd' => array(
        'driver' => 'beanstalk_extended',
        'host'   => 'my.ip.address',
        'queue'  => 'default',
        'ttr'    => 60,
    ),
    'my_fallback' => array(
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ),
);
```

In a ServiceProvider@boot :

```
/**
 * Boot the Beanstalkd queue.
 */
protected function bootQueue()
{
    $this->app['queue']->extend('beanstalk_extended', function () {
        return new BeanstalkConnector;
    });

    $this->app->bindShared('queue.failer', function($app) {
        $config = $app['config']['queue.failed'];
        return new DatabaseFailedJobProvider($app['db'], $config['database'], $config['table']);
    });

    $this->app->bindShared('queue.worker', function($app) {
        return new Worker($app['queue'], $app['queue.failer'], $app['events']);
    });
}
```

The connector :

```
<?php namespace App\Framework\Queue\Connectors;

use Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\ConnectorInterface;
use Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk as Pheanstalk;
use App\Framework\Queue\Beanstalk;

class BeanstalkConnector implements ConnectorInterface
{

/**
 * Establish a queue connection.
 *
 * @param  array $config
 * @return \Illuminate\Queue\QueueInterface
 */
    public function connect(array $config)
    {
        $pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk($config['host']);
        $bean = new Beanstalk($pheanstalk, $config['queue'], array_get($config, 'ttr', Pheanstalk::DEFAULT_TTR));
       return $bean;
    }
}
```

Then inside Beanstalkd extension :

```
/**
 * Push a new job onto the queue.
 *
 * @param  string $job
 * @param  mixed $data
 * @param  string $queue
 * @return int
 */
public function push($job, $data = '', $queue = null)
{
    try {
        $queue = $this->getQueue($queue);
        $id = parent::push($job, $data, $queue);
        return $id;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return \Queue::connection('my_fallback')->push($job, $data, $queue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, going to give it a try soon.. One question, is the `App\Framework\Queue\Beanstalk` a class extending `Illuminate\Queue\BeanstalkdQueue`?

Comment: Yessir... sorry I didn't say that before.  I also have some logic inside this class that keeps 'keys' of the jobs using Redis - so I can say Queue::exists('my.queue.job'); // true or false